# events calendar using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, backbone.js, fullcalendar

I am building an appointments calendar using the fullCalendar jquery plugin and backbone.
I am reading this tutorial here about it:[enter link description here](http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/08/05/building-a-shared-calendar-with-backbone-js-and-fullcalendar-a-step-by-step-tutorial/)

In the section "Let’s start a dialog" code is shown as to how to create a modal box and enter a new event,the code is based on the dialog widget of the jquery UI,[enter link description here](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/)

here is the code specifically:

```
render: function() {
    this.el.dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: 'New Event',
        buttons: {'Cancel': this.close}
    });
```

What I am trying to do is add more html in that dialog. I want to add a select element for example so that the user can choose the duration of the appointment.

The jquery documentation in http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/ does not indicate how to do that.
In order to get a better a picture of what I want to do is to look at the modal box that appear when you go to create an event on outlook.com calendar.

Of course the data will be sent with a ajax...but that is a different topic.

Answer (score 1):

The jqueryui dialog uses html content that's inside element you are applying plugin to.

I think it doesn't have built-in functionality to load content from external resources.

So you can either put html inside element before initializing dialog, or use its callbacks.
E.g. if you want to load data via ajax into it:

```
el.dialog({ 
modal: true,
title: 'New Event',
buttons: {'Cancel': this.close},
open: function(){
    var thisdialog = this;
    $(thisdialog).html('loading data...');
    $.post('external_resouce.html',
        function(data){
            $(thisdialog).html(data);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: First,your code looks Ok.Second, I am not talking here about an external resource here,rather just altering the HTML file with which backbone is related to. What I did after all(without being sure this is the correct approach) is just edit the HTML directly and not adding code to the function that is attached to open method like you